# Keep getting a 'self not defined' error, but the indentation seems fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, self

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """

    # sort the given array
    sorted_nums = sorted(self.nums)
    # take two indices i,j
    i = 0 #start
    j = len(sorted_nums)-1 #end

    s = sorted_nums[i]+sorted_nums[j] 

    while s != self.target:
        # move j to left if sum > target (to decrease sum) 
         if s > self.target:
            j-=1
         else:
            i+=1 # move i to right if sum < target (to increase sum)
    s = sorted_nums[i]+sorted_nums[j]
    # return corresponding indices of elements in original array
    x = self.nums.index(sorted_nums[i])
    # change value at x to avoid referring to same element twice
    self.nums[x] = -1
    y = self.nums.index(sorted_nums[j])
    return [y,x]

if __name__=='__main__':
    target = input('What is the target?')
    nums = [int(x) for x in input('Input list: x y z ...').split()]
    twoSum(self, nums, target)
```

I was thinking maybe the problem was I didn't use self in the definition of program. I still get the same problem. Tried twoSum(nums, target), and same problem.

Comment: You use `self` for class methods.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function `twoSum`, using `self` is legal, because it's the name of a parameter to the function. It's *misleading*, because normally the first parameter being named `self` means that you're writing a method of a class, and here you aren't. But it's *legal*.

---

But at the top level, there is nothing named `self`, so when you do this:

```
twoSum(self, nums, target)
```

… you get a `NameError`.

And it's not clear what you'd *want* to happen here. The only things you've defined anywhere are those `nums` and `target` variables and that `twoSum` function. There is no value anywhere that seems like an appropriate first argument to pass to `twoSum`.

---

In fact, you don't seem to have any use for `self` within the function.

You refer to things named `xelf.nums` and `self.target`, which implies that you were expecting some object with attributes named `nums` and `target`, but you haven't defined any class that has such attributes (and there's nothing builtin that does, of course).

Meanwhile, you have perfectly good parameters named `nums` and `target` that are almost certainly what you actually want to be using here.

---

Also:

> I was thinking maybe the problem was I didn't use self in the definition of program.

Nope; this isn't Go; in Python it's perfectly legal to have a variable, parameter, etc. that you never use. It's usually a bad idea, and linters might warn about it, but it won't cause an error.

More importantly, your problem is the exact opposite of that: it's not that you defined `self` and didn't use it, it's that you didn't define `self` and did try to use it.

> Tried twoSum(nums, target), and same problem.

No, you got a *different* problem. It's important to read the error messages and understand what they mean.

When Python says `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`, it's telling you how to fix the problem. Either you need to define `self` somewhere, or you have to not try to use `self`. There's no automatic way to fix that—maybe you made a typo and defined `slef` instead of `self`; maybe you meant to call a variable `self` but called it `this`; maybe there's a deeper confusion as in this case and you didn't even have a variable to use in the first place. But the ultimate problem is always that you're trying to use something that you never defined.

When Python says `TypeError: 'twoSum(num, targets)' missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'`, it's *also* telling you how to fix the problem. You tried to use a function that requires three arguments, and you only gave it two. Again, there's no automatic fix—you may have forgotten an argument, or you have may included an extra parameter that shouldn't be there on the function definition, or you may have forgotten a default value for one of your parameters, or you may have called the wrong function, etc. But the ultimate problem is always that you're passing the wrong number of arguments.

---

So, the way to fix your program is, most likely:

- Remove the `self` parameter from the `twoSum` definition.
- Replace every `self.nums` and `self.target` inside the function body with `nums` and `target`.
- Remove the `self` argument from the function call.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a simple function, not an object method. There's no `self` for you to pass in. (`self` usually holds the object to which the method belongs)

You probably also want to use the argument `sorted(nums)` rather than `sorted(self.nums)`.